# How to use .delegate with .closest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.inputRadio').closest("td").click(function (e) {
    //some code
});
```

how to use delegate in the above function? Anyone can help?

Comment: So you want to listen for events for an element's future ancestors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by calling `.closest` on `$(this)` inside the event handler:

```
$(document).delegate('.inputRadio', 'click', function () {
  var closestTd = $(this).closest('td');
  // some code
});
```

**Note:** You should use `.on` if your version of jQuery is >= `1.7`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.inputRadio', function () {
  var closestTd = $(this).closest('td');
  // some code
});
```

Comment: should note to use `on()` if version is >=1.7

Comment: Syntax for `on()` is backwards